# Как работать с компонентами основного окна из другого потока в QT?

Tags: потоки-данных, qt, c++, компоненты

Добрый вечер. Можно ли как-то из другого потока в QT изменить, допустим, текст на кнопке в осн. форме? Я делаю так: создаю структуру и помещаю в нее(сохраняю так str.component=ui->component;) те компоненты осн. формы, которые хочу изменять... Вызываю поток,и в нем пытаюсь что-то изменить, ничего не выходит... Можете привести пример кода или страницу с решением аналогичной проблемы?

Answer (score 2):

Взаимодействие главного и второстепенных потоков также можно осуществить с помощью статического метода `void QCoreApplication::postEvent(QObject* receiver,QEvent* event)`.
Сделать это можно следующим образом:

- Создаем класс, производный от `QEvent`. Атрибуты класса - данные которые мы передаем между потоками.

**Например:**

*MyEvent.h-файл*

```
#include <QEvent>

class MyEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
  MyEvent(const QString& message) : QEvent(QEvent::User) {_message = message;}
 ~MyEvent() {}

  QString message() const {return _message;}

private:
  QString _message;
};
```

Здесь `QEvent::User` - идентификатор пользовательсокго события, `_message` - данные, передаваемые между потоками.

- В **отправителе данных** (второстепенный поток) в куче создаем объект события пользовательского типа, задаем значения соответствующих атрибутов и помещаем его в очередь событий получателя данных.

**Например:**

```
void MyThread::run()
{
  forever
  {
    ...
    MyEvent* myEvent = new MyEvent("Hello GUI! This is another thread.");    
    QCoreApplication::postEvent(gui, myEvent);    
    ...
  }
}
```

Здесь `gui` - указатель на объект-получатель данных.

- В **получателе данных** (GUI-поток) переопределяем виртуальный метод `bool QObject::event(QEvent* event)`. Метод обрабатывает все события для виджета, поступающие из его очереди событий. Если идентификатор события имеет пользовательский тип, то мы выполняем преобразование типа события к пользовательскому с последующим получением значений его атрибутов и возвращаем значение true чтобы не передавать событие для обработки родительскому классу. Если же идентификатор события имеет тип отличный от пользовательского, то мы передаем его родительскому классу для дальнейшей обработки.

**Например:**

*Widget.h-файл (GUI-поток)*

```
class Widget : public QWidget, public Ui::WidgetClass
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~Widget();

protected:
  bool event(QEvent* event);
...
```

*Widget.cpp-файл (GUI-поток)*

```
bool Widget::event(QEvent* event)
{
  if (event->type() == QEvent::User)
  {
    MyEvent* postedEvent = static_cast<MyEvent*>(event);

    textEdit->append(postedEvent->message());

    return true;
  }

  return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

Также справедлива передача событий в обратном направлении - от GUI-потока ко второстепенному потоку.

Пример передачи событий в обоих направления можно скачать [тут](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/103588168/HC_3.tar.gz).

Answer (score 1):

Не копал глубоко qt, но едва ли получится как у вас - гуй обычно обрабатывается основным потоком и попытка менять его из не основного ни к чему хорошему не приводит.
Когда мне нужно было сделать что-то в этом роде я завел сигнал в потоке (наследнике QThread) и слот в виджете со строкой в качестве параметра и посылал его стандартно через emit, насколько верно - не знаю, когда это писал вроде где-то в справке нашел что так и надо, но уже не помню

Comment: Неужели нет варианта проще(((

Comment: @Alerr, нет.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте любой произвольный сигнал, который будет вызываться из потока. Можете даже его сразу снабдить аргументом со строкой. Когда же будете его подключать, добавьте к методу `QObject::connect()` флаг `Qt::QueuedConnection`. Таким образом вызывающийся слот будет выполнен в очереди событий главного окна.